# Symfony 4 DQL - Query returning null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Booking entity with a bookingStart property.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $bookingStart;
```

I create an object called `$filledSlots`, that contains all bookings in `$bookingRepository` that match a given day.

```
$today = (new \DateTime())->setTime(0,0);
$filledSlots = $bookingRepository->getBookingsForDay($today);
```

I have created a method to query the Bookings table:

```
function getBookingsForDay(\DateTime $day) {

    //Build query
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->andWhere('b.bookingStart = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $day)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

But when I dump $filledSlots it is empty:

```
ProfileController.php on line 60:
[]
```

I definitely have at least one booking in database for the todays date. Is the query not correct to find all by current day?

Comment: If you need to store just date, without time - it is better to use `date` type for column, not `datetime`

Comment: I will need time a well, as the filledSlots will populate a daily schedule with 12 30 min slots.

Comment: Then you need to use dates range as @Yoshi wrote in his answer

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the stored entity has a datetime value with hours/minutes and such. As such you'd need to hit exactly that time to get a result.

You could try one or more of the following:

- use [`date`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/types.html#date) instead of datetime
- query with a database-compatible format, e.g.

  ```
  ->setParameter('val', $day->format('Y/m/d'))
  ```
- try finding dates between a certain date, e.g. `->andWhere('b.bookingStart BETWEEN :start AND :end')` supplying `start` as *`today 00:00:00`* and `end` as *`today 23:59:59`* (pseudo values!)

---

Also you might want to check how `$bookingStart` is set in the first place. If this is simply:

```
 $this->bookingStart = new \DateTime('now'); // or similar
```

you'll have a *time fraction* in the db.